# Elegant system calls in haskell

Tags: haskell, kerberos, system-calls

I'm making a web-site where users can log in using the kerberos service. Though, it's quite irrelevant for my problem.

Since I'm using kerberos I want to use a system call to invoke `kinit`, but I don't know the best way to do it.

So far I got:

```
module Kerberos where

system :: String -> IO ExitCode
-- system is loaded through imports

type Username = String
type Password = String

kerberosValidate :: Username -> Password -> IO Bool
kerberosValidate username password = fmap (== ExitSuccess) $ 
  system $ "echo " ++ password ++ " | kinit " ++ username
```

Something like that, which should work so-so. I have three problems with this though.

- There is no escaping of the `username` and `password` strings. This is important since there being a website passing any received input to this function.
- Ideally `password` should not be passed to `kinit` process with `echo password |`. Is there some function taking standard in as an argument?
- Similarly for `username`, `username` should be passed as an argument. I think `rawSystem` solves this though.

Is there any system-function that helps me out here?

Comment: You probably want to use`createProcess` and pipe your input to the child's `stdin`.

Comment: @n.m.: You should probably leave that as an answer--as far as I can tell that handles the second two problems neatly. Short answers are fine if they're useful, whereas comments often get overlooked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `createProcess` and friends from [`System.Process`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/process/1.0.1.5/doc/html/System-Process.html#g:1).

---

A note on security: I'd advise against passing any strings through uninterpreted. You could easily write a parser for your commands, build a Haskell AST out of the result of the parse that is guaranteed to be safe, then render that to the system command. That way you'd get a static guarantee against string injection attacks, enforced by the type of the parser.

Comment: Thanks. For future reference I would like to point out that `readProcessWithExitCode` came to best use for me. Another thing, what is necessary to safely escape characters for shell parameters? Is it even necessary if the String is actually passed as an argument to `readProcessWithExitCode`?